# Why an anova after lme (or lm)

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme

I would like to understand why an anova is made on a lme (or lmer) and how to interpret the anova output.

```r
lm1 <- lme(EWL..mg.h. ~ Condition*Session + Condition*Sex + 
    Condition*Mass, random =  ~1|Individu, 
    data = data_respiro_acoustic)

summary(m1)
Anova(m1, type = c("III"))
```

Summary Output :

```r
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: data_respiro_acoustic 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1232.332 1261.459 -606.1662

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Individu
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    18.01137  13.9361

Fixed effects:  EWL..mg.h. ~ Condition * Session + Condition * Sex + Condition *      Mass 
                               Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)                 32.45663 25.611020 103  1.267292  0.2079
ConditionS                  17.14916 17.503442 103  0.979759  0.3295
SessionSession_2             2.68361  3.284770 103  0.816986  0.4158
SexM                         8.13412  7.651439  33  1.063083  0.2955
Mass                         0.03087  0.107194  33  0.288001  0.7751
ConditionS:SessionSession_2 -5.78778  4.645366 103 -1.245925  0.2156
ConditionS:SexM             21.74791  5.193698 103  4.187364  0.0001
ConditionS:Mass              0.00369  0.072762 103  0.050762  0.9596
 Correlation: 
                            (Intr) CndtnS SssS_2 SexM   Mass   CS:SS_ CnS:SM
ConditionS                  -0.342                                          
SessionSession_2            -0.064  0.094                                   
SexM                        -0.558  0.188  0.000                            
Mass                        -0.980  0.330  0.000  0.447                     
ConditionS:SessionSession_2  0.045 -0.133 -0.707  0.000  0.000              
ConditionS:SexM              0.189 -0.554  0.000 -0.339 -0.152  0.000       
ConditionS:Mass              0.333 -0.973  0.000 -0.152 -0.339  0.000  0.447

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.1236561 -0.6115711  0.1679837  0.6287077  2.3180579 

Number of Observations: 144
Number of Groups: 36
```

Anova Output

```r
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: EWL..mg.h.
                    Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)        1.6060  1     0.2051    
Condition          0.9599  1     0.3272    
Session            0.6675  1     0.4139    
Sex                1.1301  1     0.2877    
Mass               0.0829  1     0.7733    
Condition:Session  1.5523  1     0.2128    
Condition:Sex     17.5340  1  2.822e-05 ***
Condition:Mass     0.0026  1     0.9595
```

I would also like to know what type of anova should I do and why.

Comment: Welcome to CV, have you tried searching the site? For example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204940/anova-vs-summary-in-the-analysis-of-models-and-variables), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500722/model-interpretation-in-r-anova-vs-summary-output), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499104/different-output-between-summarylm-and-anovalm-in-r), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249884/conflicting-results-of-summary-and-anova-for-a-mixed-model-with-interactions)...